# How to show angular bootstrap-modal on page load only once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, session, bootstrap-modal, angular-bootstrap

I can show the bootstrap modal on page load, the modal is triggering even when route changed. like if i returned to the same page from other page using browser back button or forward button. if it shows on page reload, that is ok to me, but on route change also it is showing. 
this is the code i am using to show on page load.i have tried some solutions online but didn't worked.it may be the possible duplicate. but the other solutions not working for me. i have tried with onroutechangestart -->to hide, but it is still showing, how to do it . can anyone please help me.

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
   $scope.showModal = true;
});
```

Comment: the code that you have provided will show Modal whenever your DOM is ready. In which state or route do you want the modal to show and not in other??

Comment: I am using normal ngRoute rather than ui router. i want that modal to display only in `/home` and if i click back from other page, it should n't show it again

Comment: it is also ok, if it based on session.i.e(once per session). how to do it with session, can you please help me

Comment: umm why don't you maintain a count in localstorage and have the logic bound to it??. That would be one way to do it.

Comment: if you don't mind, can you write answer, how you are telling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a factory which control the state of your app

```
app.factory('startFact',function(){

        var isStarted = false;

        return{
            isStarted: function(){
                return isStarted;
            },

            startApp: function(){
                isStarted = true;
            },
        };
    });
```

In the controller

```
app.controller('mainCtrl', ['$scope','startFact', function ($scope, startFact) {
        $scope.init = function () {

            if (!startFact.isStarted()) {
                $scope.showModal = true;
                startFact.startApp();
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Call the init function

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-init="init()">
```

Comment: Instead we can use ng-init=toggleModal function, which initiates the modal, but the issue is , it will show if i go to same page from other page using back button or some  redirection. it should show only once.
i have tried your code too. same issue

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your answer is simple. i was thinking to use session , localstorage making complicated

Comment: Great, happy to help :) yes, localstorage can make things a bit ugly and more complicated then it should be